# Pooling mysql on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection-string

I'm using mysql database for my site, i want to use mysql pooling.

How do I implement mysql pooling on c# environment ?

i"m using the connection string like this example :

```
User ID=root;Password=myPassword;Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase; Direct=true;Protocol=TCP;Compress=false;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `pooling=True` to the connection string

Comment: is it enough only to add popling = true to the connection string?

Comment: it is not working i change my connection string , i think i need to implement it on the c# code too , i"m getting execeptions errors on the open connection and the close

Comment: Which exceptions are you getting? I have the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682941/mysql-maxpoolsize-not-applied-in-aws-rds

Answer (score -2):

Concerning connections string **ConnectionStrings.com** is a very valuable resource. Specific for MySql just click [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql).